# gzip configuration inside nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

I want to activate the gzip compression in my application server. As it's an nginx server I checked and I already have my gzip configuration ready, but I don´t know where to place it inside my nginx.conf file.

Inside the file there's a few server blocks, as there's an API for json data and another one for the js and other assets.
There are also a couple other projects I don´t want to touch. So it's something like this:

```
server {
  listen 443;

  location...
  ...
}

server {
  ...
}

server {
  ...
}
```

Now, my gzip configuration is inside http {}, but where should I place this? My guess is it should go inside every server I want to update. So something like this

```
server {
  ...
  http {
  }
}

server {
  ...
}

server {
  ...
  http {
  ...
  }
}
```

Is this correct or is http a global section?

Thanks

EDIT.
Ok, it seems that server actually goes inside the http, so my question... if gzip is enabled... it's enabled for everything? what if I want to enable gzip for an application only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `gzip` configuration can be placed inside an `http` section, a `server` section, or a `location` section. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html) for the available contexts of each directive.

The `http` section is one of the outermost blocks that contains all of the `server` sections. If you are looking at a file that contains `server` blocks at the top level, **it is not your `nginx` configuration**. It is part of your `nginx` configuration.

The `nginx` configuration file is almost always called `nginx.conf` and located somewhere like `/etc/nginx/` or `/usr/local/etc/nginx/`. This file may contain `include` directives to pull in configuration from other files (e.g. `sites-enabled` and/or `conf.d`).

If these `gzip` directives apply to a single application, place them in the relevant `server` or `location` block, **without an inner `http` container**.